# How to solve $Ax=b$ wihout inverting $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, lu-decomposition

I'm going to solve this equation:

$$Ax=b$$

Onto an embedded system with using C-programing language. It need to be fast as possible. Assume that $A$ is not square. One way to solve this is to use:

$$x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T b$$

But I have heard from this page that solving $Ax=b$ should not be done by inverting $A$.

> What do you do if you need to solve $Ax = b$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix?
>   Isn’t the solution $A^{-1} b$? Yes, theoretically. But that doesn’t mean
>   you need to actually find $A^{-1}$. Solving the equation $Ax = b$ is faster
>   than finding $A^{-1}$. Books might write the problem as $x = A^{-1} b$, but that
>   doesn’t mean they expect you to calculate it that way.

https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

So is there any method to solve $Ax=b$ without inverting $A$?
I'm talking about

$$\min (Ax-b = 0)$$

Comment: Read the comments of that same blog post and they give you several methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for 2 different problems. If you need to solve $Ax=b$, and output no solution when no solution exists, a good first stop is [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

If you need to find $\min_x \|Ax-b\|^2$, you are looking for [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) solver.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want only to find $x$ from the equation $Ax=b$. Is Gaussian Elimination the fastest? I have heard that there is Gauss-Jordan Elimination too. Who is better if I know that the system can be solved and also I want to solve it as fast as possible?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson look at the computational efficiency section in the Wiki article. Consider *Numerical Recipes In C++* for a good prototype

Comment: Hmm....I think I need to use the least square instead of Gaussian Elimination due to my $A$ matrix is not square.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Gaussian Elimination works perfectly fine on rectangular matrices.

Comment: According to Jean-Marc Valin here, I need to use $x = (A^T A)^{-1}A^Tb$ if I want to use Gaussian Elimination och nonsquare matrix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201696/gauss-elimination-for-nxm-matrix

Comment: @DanielMårtensson $(A^T A)^{-1}A^T b$ is basically a formula for linear least squares solution of the system $Ax =b$. The way to do this is compute $M = A^T A$ and $v = A^T b$ using straight matrix multiplication and then solve $Mx = v$ using Gauss-Jordan Elimination.

Comment: I will remember that! :) Thanks!